# How to give multiline & single line comment in translation PO file?

Tags: comments, translation, odoo, po

How to give multiline & single line comment in translation PO file ?

I am not able to give multiline comment in po translation file in odoo , I have to comment 2000 line code at once
So how can it done ?

Comment: Do you have an example of that line? I suppose your code is like a message too long. The original text may be wrapped in the PO file.

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: You can just remove them

Comment: I am using gedit @ChesuCR , I have not permission to remove because it will be used in future , so I have to make it in comment , it is 2000 lines of code

Comment: OK, then you can use some other editor with more features, like sublime or eclipse. You can create a shortcut to comment 2000 lines at the same time.

Comment: by using other editors , in translation arabic it gives a reverse string opposite of I found in google translate , so for the perfect string I have to use gedit only , I have sublime but it gives me opposite output of gedit in arabic that is wrong

Answer (score 0):

According to [these docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html), multi-line comments aren't possible in PO files.